# Is there an ovaloid that is not topologically equivalent to a sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces

Topologically speaking, the compact and connected surfaces are classified into three kinds of surfaces:

- a sphere
- a connected sum of tori
- a connected sum of projective planes.

Also, we know that:

- the sphere is an ovaloid
- ovaloids are compact and connected and therefore can be put in one of these categories.

Is there an ovaloid not topologically equivalent to a sphere?

How could I prove that there exist or not an ovaloid that is not topologically equivalent to a sphere?

Comment: An ovaloid is given by the equation $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1$. There is a simple change of coordinates that describes an explicit diffeomorphism of an ovaloid with the sphere

Comment: @leibnewtz this is the equation of the ellipsoid, an ellipsoid is an ovaloid, but there ovaloids which aren't an ellipsoid.

Comment: Thanks @SaucyO'Path, it is already edited.

Comment: @EvaMGG I was just going off the first thing I found on google. What's your definition?

Comment: @leibnewtz An ovaloid is a connected and compact surface whose Gauss curvature is always positive.

Comment: How do you define "ovaloid", and what kind of topological equivalence are you talking about that only gives rise to three classes of surfaces?

Comment: Well apparently Liebmann's theorem answers your question if the surface is closed.

Comment: @Henrik I changed the question, maybe this is better. And the definition of ovaloid is a surface that is compact, connected and its Gauss curvature is always positive.

Comment: The Gauss-Bonnet theorem forces your space to be either a sphere or projective plane: everything else has nonpositive Euler characteristic.

Comment: @MikeMiller so I guess I need figure out that ovaloids have positive Euler characteristic...is there a relation between the Euler characteristic and Gauss curvature?

Comment: The Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

Comment: @MikeMiller You should give an official answer. See also  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/808203.

Comment: You can check corollary 5.3.5.1 http://www.mat.ucm.es/~jlafuent/Docencia/cys/cyslc.pdf stating that every ovaloid is homeomorphic to a sphere. Even more, there is a theorem given by hadamard stating that any ovalid is diffeomorphic to a sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take as a reference [these notes](http://www.mat.ucm.es/~jlafuent/Docencia/cys/cyslc.pdf) (check corollary 5.3.5.1). The corollary states the following:

> If $M$ is a differentiable surface of $\mathbb{R}^3$ connected and
>   compact with Gauss curvature $K \ge 0$ and not identically zero then
>   $M$ is homeomorphic to a sphere.

My understanding is that one requires differentiability to be able to use Gauss curvature.

Now, the ingredients to arrive to this corollary are the following:

- a classification of  topological surfaces which you cite and which is stated at  theorem 5.3.5.1 of the document.
- the Gauss-Bonnet theorem which has been mentionned in the comments and appears in the document at theorem 5.3.4.1.
- Realize that homeomorphic implies homotopy equivalent.

In fact, the document cites a stronger result by Hadamard in theorem 5.3.6.2:

> If $M$ is an ovalid then the Gauss map $\stackrel{\to}{N}: M \to
>  \mathbb{S}^2$ associated with any unitary normal $N$ is a
>    dipheomorphism. In particular, $M$ is dipheomorphic to a sphere.

So as you can see you need quite a bit of machinery to prove the result. However you get to a nice result for ovaloids.